# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes)

Tags: php

I'm currently busy on my new CMS. I'm at the part that I can go ahead to test my TPL & Paging system. Now, the only thing is, when I go to `http://localhost/` I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\application\classes\class.functions.php on line 162
```

So normally, I'd go to line 162 of `Class.functions.php`, see if I'm in a loop or anything, clear what the hell is going on there and test it again. Now, the fun thing is, my `class.functions.php` only contains 92 lines. :')

Is there anyone who has any experience with this?

Thanks,

Wesley.

Comment: Gotta be an endless loop somewhere.

Comment: @Utkanos I got that already, the only thing is, how to find it lawl...

Comment: Shot in the dark, but try looking at line 81. It's possible your line endings are messed up and PHP is counting them wrong.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Nope, it's totally clean...

Comment: You've got a memory leak (sorry to declaim the obvious). It probably has nothing to do with `Class.functions.php` but that is the point at which the PHP interpreter is blowing up. If you're really desperate, try a binary search (somewhat crude): comment out half of the code in your front page and see if it still blows up (obviously the page won't render as you wish). If it does die, flip the commented lines to confirm. If it doesn't, assume those lines are innocent. Keep cutting the comments in half in order to find that bit which is melting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recomend you to use this but try to do:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","-1");
```

This means no memmory limit.

Comment: Dude, the thing is eating all available memory. Allowing PHP to exceed it's local limits will take longer; but ultimately simply kill the application providing web service (apache nginx..) and possible the entire server. Not really a good idea.

Comment: I told you i don't recommend you to do this on live server. but try it in local to see how much memmory will script eat, is there end?
Also you can post your code to see more details.